# angular 6 - ngOnChanges not firing for nested array

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a `toSpecialities` object that has two arrays `specialitiesOptions` and `specialities`, i send this object from parent component to child component

```
this.toSpecialities = { specialitiesOptions: specialities, specialities: this.exerciseFramework.specialities };
<ef-specialties [data]="toSpecialities"></ef-specialties>
```

in the child component i used `ngOnChanges` to detect the change of object

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ef-specialties'
})
export class SpecialtiesComponent implements OnChanges {

    @Input()
    public data: any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes["data"] && changes["data"].currentValue) {
          console.log(changes["data"]);
        }
    }

}
```

when i update the `specialities`, i can't detect the change of `toSpecialities` object in the child component

```
this.toSpecialities.specialities = this.array.specialities;
```

Comment: Does the `this.exerciseFramework.specialities` and `this.array.specialities` contain the same values?

Comment: It is working like this as designed ...

Comment: @MichaelD yes the same values

Comment: The `ngOnChanges` will only fire when the `previousValue` and `currentValue` is different. For such cases, a singleton service with shared data would be a better fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `ngOnChanges` is only fired when the objet reference changes for `@Input` properties. So it will be triggered if you change the input value for a simple type property (string, boolean, number) value, but it will not be triggered if you change an object's property.

Try this if you want `ngOnChanges` to fire

```
this.toSpecialities = {...this.toSpecialities, 
   specialities : this.array.specialities};
```

This will clone `this.toSpecialities` and change the `specialities` value of the clone. Changing the value of `toSpecialities` will trigger `ngOnChanges`